# Mesh Network Topology with 'Prosumer' Equipment

Tags: networking, switch

I have several devices I would like to connect in a mesh type architecture on our home network. The main router is a Ubiquiti EdgeRouter X, and a handful of TP Link Easy Smart switches. Nothing fancy.

Currently, I have...

- **Router** connected to **Switch 1** with one link.
- **Switch 1** and **Switch 2** linked with a 2 way Link Aggregation connection.
- **Switch 3** connected to **Switch 2** with a single link.
- I have some servers on both **Switch 1** and **Switch 2** which clients all over the network need high speed access to.

I have it configured this way to allow two gigabit clients or many 10/100 clients to saturate that LAG connection between the two switches. However, a client on **Switch 3** would violate the three hop rule to access the internet connection. (1-**Switch3**, 2-**Switch 2**, 3-**Switch 1**, 4-**Router**).

I want to change the topology so that **Switch 2** could act more like a core switch than an edge switch.

Ideally I would like **Switch 1** and **Switch 2** to be connected to the router with a single link each for their internet connection, then connected to each other with another link for traffic accessing servers between the switches.

That would obviously create a loop, which my understanding is that would generate network issues.

I'm not sure if it affects anything, but all the switch links are VLAN Trunks, not just dumb links. The network is running 4 different VLANs for General, Security, Voice and Guest.

So my question, would this type of mesh topology be possible with the aforementioned consumer equipment? Would this require any special configuration?

Image attached of the topology I would like to move to.

[image: new-topology]

Comment: What "three hop rule"? Are you thinking of the old "repeater rule" from the 1990's? That only applied to hubs, not switches.

Comment: @Spiff When I first started doing IT it was explained to me that there was a general rule that from any point in your network there should be no more than three active hardware devices (switches, routers, AP's) between the client and the destination. (Like client to internal server, or client to ISP connection)

Comment: Yeah, that "rule" doesn't make any sense. Avoiding unnecessary hops is good, but 3 isn't a magic number.

Comment: You may be overdesigning this. I count 5 devices in your network, so unless you have some crazy intensive network traffic for home use, a single switch/router should easily handle all of it. Including VLANs, if you insist on using them.

Comment: @dirkt: There are 5 devices in the _diagram_, I wouldn't assume that it 100% corresponds to the actual network. I sure wouldn't want to draw hundreds of individual computers across five buildings just to illustrate a connection between core switches...

Comment: @dirkt Yeah, the diagram is significantly cut down for the purposes of the question.

Comment: @Spiff Well disregarding that old rule, I guess that renders my question null, as the mesh topology isn't really needed. More out of my personal interest now, I'm still interested in what would need to be done configuration wise to make a mesh network work.

Comment: Then it might sense to actually describe in the question what number of devices you are talking about, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm still interested in what would need to be done configuration wise to make a mesh network work.

The "mesh network" will actually make it harder for the switches than a simple star topology, because it creates loops, and the switches must work harder to avoid those loops (which would flood your network with packets going in circles, saturate the links and make it unusuable).

There's a standard protocol for this, the [spanning tree protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol), which will thin out your mesh until it's a star-like topology (a "tree").

So all switches (including the router, which has an integrated switch) should support this protocol, and have it enabled. Nothing else should be needed.

This also means the extra connections in the mesh won't buy you anything in terms of throughput (though they provide redundancy).